# Stored Procedure Selete First Row in Excel File with Openrowset

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I am exporting an mssql query to an excel file which has the first two rows as a header. The first row (title) is one cell that spans from A1:K1. The second row (header) has 11 cells and spans from A2:K2. I would like to have an openrowset to change the title and a second openrowset to populate the excel file.

This doesn't work:

```
    EXEC('INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''' + @provider + ''',''' + @ExcelString + ''',''SELECT Top 1 * FROM [Sheet1$]'') 
SELECT Top 1 [Customer] FROM [ORDER SUMMERY] WHERE [Order #] = ''' + @OrderNumber + ''' AND (Status = ''C'' OR Status = ''I'')')
```

This is the second part and it does work:

```
    EXEC('INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''' + @provider + ''',''' + @ExcelString + ''',''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A3:K3]'') 
SELECT [ITEMNUMBER],[CustomerSKU],[ITEM_DESCRIPTION],[CASEPACK],[Total Qty],[Case Price],[CASEPACK]*[Total Qty],[Total Qty]*[Case Price],[Unit Price],[PreTicketInfo],[Quote #] FROM [ORDER SUMMERY] WHERE [Order #] = ''' + @OrderNumber + ''' AND (Status = ''C'' OR Status = ''I'')')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EXEC('INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''' + @provider + ''',''' + @ExcelString + ''',''SELECT Top 1 * FROM [Sheet1$A1]'')  
SELECT Top 1 [Customer] FROM [ORDER SUMMERY] WHERE [Order #] = ''' + @OrderNumber + ''' AND (Status = ''C'' OR Status = ''I'')')
```

Try this. Excel holds the value of merged cells in the top left of the merged cell range, so a merged spell spanning A1:K1 would be programmatically referred to as cell A1 when pulling value data

Comment: Tried the above and got this: `OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$A1'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.".
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".`

Comment: Tried this: `EXEC('INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''' + @provider + ''',''' + @ExcelString + ''',''SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Sheet1$]'') 
 SELECT Top 1 [Customer] FROM [ORDER SUMMERY] WHERE [Order #] = ''' + @OrderNumber + ''' AND (Status = ''C'' OR Status = ''I'')')`
                                                                     And got this: `Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`